# Does fsutil utility write any data to the hard disk?

Tags: fsutil

If I created a 100 gb file with the fsutil utility in windows, it takes up space on my hard drive, however it takes only a few seconds to create such a large file.

How does windows produce such a large file and does it physically take up any file space? I.e. overwrite any sectors on the disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTFS is an [extent-based file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extent_(file_systems)), so basically, the file system just keeps track of the allocated size of the file and what parts have been written to. If an unwritten part is read, the file system just returns zeroes, so it doesn't need to actually write out a bunch of zeroes during allocation.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, (as an example) when a torrent file is being readied for download, say a 5gb file, it will allocate that space on the hard disk so it isn't taken up by something else and as the file continuous to download it fills that space with actual data?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. A torrent client may implement it that way, but it may also choose to create [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) instead, in which case space is not actually allocated until written. This can result in increased fragmentation, but there will be more disk space available for use while the data has not been completely downloaded and written to disk.